# Insert custom setter in maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, jaxb, setter, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm using the [org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin](http://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home) to create POJOs from XSD schema files.

Now I want to insert something like a custom setter. It should trim all Strings and should remove certain characters.

Do you know how to do this?

---

**The XJB file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="my-schema-xml4.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.String" adapter="my.StringAdapter" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

---

**Solution for binding Java types:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
    <bindings schemaLocation="mySchema-xml4.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <globalBindings>
            <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.String" xmlType="xs:string"
                adapter="com.name.MyAdapter" />
                    <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.String" xmlType="xs:anySimpleType"
                adapter="com.name.MyAdapter" />
        </globalBindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

---

But the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` still isn't added to the `content` property in nodes with mixed content, although the property has the type `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to achieve this is to implement an own XmlAdapter and configure it via the property customization.
You can do this with a standard `jaxb:property` customization or with the [annotate plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin).

`jaxb:property`:

```
  <jaxb:property>
    <jaxb:baseType>
      <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.String"
        adapter="com.acme.foo.MyAdapter"/>
    </jaxb:baseType>
  </jaxb:property>
```

Annotate plugin:

```
  <annox:annotate target="field">
    <annox:annotate
      annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter"
      value="com.acme.foo.MyAdapter"/>
  </annox:annotate>
```

See the sample project here:

https://svn.java.net/svn/jaxb2-commons~svn/basics/trunk/tests/one/

Comment: I've implemented the XmlAdapter, but I don't know how to append it. Please see my XJB file in the edited question.

Comment: Please re-read my answer, `jaxb:property` is the way to go. There's also a link to a sample project - have you checked that?

Comment: I've re-read your answer and also checked the sample project, but I don't know where to append the `jaxb:property` when I want it to affect all Strings in the schema.

Comment: Ah, all string. I have to check.

Comment: I've found out how to parse types (see my edited answer), but I still can't parse values in nodes.

Comment: > But the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter still isn't added to the content
> property in nodes with mixed content, although the property has the
> type java.lang.String.

These are probably just a few cases, try to address them with the annotate plugin (one of the options I've listed).

Answer (score 0):

If your XSD will not change in the future just generate the POJOs, comment out the JAXB plugin and modify the source by hand.

If your XSD changes *rarely* you still can use this solution with a version control system. Commit the generated source, modify the POJOs and commit the modifications. Next time when the XSD is modified generate a patch between the two commits, generate the POJOs from the new XSD and apply the patch. I found this solution a lot simpler in cases where the XSD almost never changes.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the exception `javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found` when I want to create a new `XMLInputFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach would be to use a StAX `StreamReaderDelegate` to manipulate the XML text before it was received by the JAXB implementation.

**Demo**

Your code would look something like the following.  You would implement a `StreamReaderDelegate` to manipulate the text returned from the text events:

```
package forum7329881;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("src/forum7329881/input.xml"));
        xsr = new MyStreamReaderDelegate(xsr);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

    private static class MyStreamReaderDelegate extends StreamReaderDelegate {

        public MyStreamReaderDelegate(XMLStreamReader xsr) {
            super(xsr);
        }


        @Override
        public String getText() {
            return super.getText().trim();
        }

        @Override
        public char[] getTextCharacters() {
            return getText().toCharArray();
        }

        @Override
        public int getTextLength() {
            return getText().length();
        }

        @Override
        public int getTextStart() {
            return 0;
        }

    }

}
```

**input.xml**

Below is sample input that contains whitespace in the text nodes:

```
<customer Id="1">
    <name>    Jane Doe    </name>
    <address>
        <street>    123 A Street    </street>
    </address>
</customer>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
    <address>
        <street>123 A Street A</street>
    </address>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
</customer>
```

**Customer**

```
package forum7329881;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private Address address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

**Address**

```
package forum7329881;

public class Address {

    private String street;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

Below is a link to a more detailed example where I used a StAX `StreamReaderDelegate` to support case insensitive unmarshalling:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/case-insensitive-unmarshalling.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use AOP, 
Pick Spring AOP, for instance, Intercept the Adapter methods to have trim / strip logic. In fact this can now be a generic logic that would apply to all string types.
If this sounds convincing, I can further help with the code

Comment: I'd just need to know where to insert the interceptor.